# How to get a count of a variable in an array in Angular 8

Tags: angular, angular8

Here is my sample data

```
    this.factorList = [ 
    {      
    factorEnrollment: "OPTIONAL",
    factorProvider: "OKTA",
    factorStatus: "NOT_SETUP",
    factorType: "call"
  },
    {  
    factorEnrollment: "OPTIONAL",
    factorProvider: "OKTA",
    factorStatus: "NOT_SETUP",
    factorType: "sms"
  },
  {  
    factorEnrollment: "REQUIRED",
    factorProvider: "OKTA",
    factorStatus: "NOT_SETUP",
    factorType: "sms"
  }
    ];
```

How to get a count of how many FactorEnrollment: "REQUIRED" is in the array above in angular 8?

Comment: I would say, it is not related to the Angular but you can use something like this :

this.factorList.filter(d => d.factorEnrollment === "REQUIRED").length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter the array by the required condition and get the length of that array.

```js
const factorList = [ 
    {      
    factorEnrollment: "OPTIONAL",
    factorProvider: "OKTA",
    factorStatus: "NOT_SETUP",
    factorType: "call"
  },
    {  
    factorEnrollment: "OPTIONAL",
    factorProvider: "OKTA",
    factorStatus: "NOT_SETUP",
    factorType: "sms"
  },
  {  
    factorEnrollment: "REQUIRED",
    factorProvider: "OKTA",
    factorStatus: "NOT_SETUP",
    factorType: "sms"
  }
    ];
    
 
 const filtered = factorList.filter(x => x.factorEnrollment === 'REQUIRED');
 
 console.log('Number of required:', filtered.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
let count = this.factorList.filter(x => x.factorEnrollment == "REQUIRED").length
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jlzeal?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter method like

```
 let count = this.factorList.filter(x => x.factorEnrollment === 'REQUIRED').length;
```

Answer (score 0):

@Margerine

You can use the array methods of 'filter'

```
`factorList.filter(factor => factor.factorEnrollment === 'REQUIRED')`
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the javascript array.filter operator.

```
let matches: number = this.factoryList.filter( item => item.factorEnrollment === 'REQUIRED').length
```

that will return the count of how many items match your criteria

you could also use `reduce` operator if you'd like